# SQL Job used as JobScheduler

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs, job-scheduling

Was thinking about using a job to run my other jobs in sequence.

What are your thoughts about doing this?

[image: JobScheduler]

So within "Job Scheduler" I have

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JOB1'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JOB2'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JOB3'
```

And this package is set to run at 6:00AM completing approx. in 3-4 hours.

The idea came up because the packages need to run in sequence and the time of the packages can change from running 1-2 hours depending on amount of data.

Any reasons why I should NOT do it this way or is this a good way of doing this??

---------------EDIT---------------

This will not work since the steps will run right after the prior jobs has started. NOT waiting for the prior step to complete...

Is there some standard syntax that checks for step completion?

So the steps would be something like:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JOB1'
--Wait for completion then run next step
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JOB2'
--Wait for completion then run next step
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JOB3'
```

?

Comment: Any reason why you don't create one job with a number of job steps?

Comment: Not sure about it, meaning you want to run 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JOB1'
Within Job step 1 
etc.?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this? MS SQL Server? (please tag your question accordingly)